# How to kill a long running query on Netezza when you have no admin/root/sudo access

Tags: netezza, aginity

I ran a select query on Netezza where I do not have admin rights and it has been running for last 2 hours now. How do I kill it? I thought of dropping the session, but it says I must have Abort rights.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough one. You basically ask how to hack the system :)

Only thought that comes to mind: look in the _v_session_detail and locate the ip address and process ID of the running query. Then (have someone) kill that process or disconnect the machine from the network for a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

1) First identify session:

```
select qs_sessionid from _v_qrystat where qs_tstart >='date';
```

2) You will find the `qs_sessionid`, then do the following:

```
drop session
<qs_sessionid>;
```